# I need to rewrite URL with CakePHP 2

Tags: cakephp, url-rewriting

I have setup cakephp and URL is of form http://example.com/pages/search?search=delhi and this needs to be shown like http://example.com/doctor/delhi.

Can anyone please suggest how this will be done.

Comment: Routing is CakePHP 101, please start with reading [**the docs**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html), try to implement what you've learned, and if you then have a specific problem, check back and explain it.

Answer (score 0):

CakePhp already has such routing.

You can create a DoctorController  and in the index() u can use the first parameter.

Further, You may also use .htaccess Rewrite in your way.

Comment: I want it from routes or htacess.

Comment: You can get your parameters using $this->request->params after u create doctor controller, using cakephp routes